# Insert some lines of code to other projects

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

i have one project (let's call it project1) that is going to add properties to another project's class. The thing is I wanted to make it automatically. So in my project there are two lines of code which I want to add at the bottom of the class.vb or class.cs in a project called project2. Is it possible? If so, how?
It is a data access builder software which after adding some new columns to our database we use it to generate its properties  and its parameter to be added in BLL. Since we do it often (changing our database structure) I did not wanted to copy data from data access builder software and add it to project2 manually. So that's it!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for: Do you want to copy/paste source code? Reuse code? Runtime access?

Comment: More information about what the two lines are and why you want them everywhere would help. As it is, the question is too vague to answer without guessing.

Comment: i edited my question guys. Is it a bit more clear now?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to mess around automatically within your solution you can do this, by combining

- [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)
- [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.aspx)

I used it to automatically add a bunch of auto-generated resource files. I stripped the code a little bit down, so if it doesn't work, simply uncomment the `Debugger.Launch()` line and debug the code in a new VS instance.

```
<#@ template inherits="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ModelingTextTransformation" language="C#v3.5" debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Design.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Drawing.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="envdte.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.CodeDom.Compiler" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Drawing" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Resources" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Resources.Tools" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.CSharp" #>

<#
    var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.Host.TemplateFile);
    var resourcesPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "Resources");
#>

This template file doesn't create any usable source file.

The resource files where added at: <#= System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() #> <#= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() #>
<#

    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

    EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)((IServiceProvider)this.Host)
                       .GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

    EnvDTE.Projects projects = dte.Solution.Projects;
    EnvDTE.Project iconProject = projects.Cast<EnvDTE.Project>().Where(p => p.Name == "Icons").Single();
    EnvDTE.ProjectItem resourcesFolder = iconProject.ProjectItems.Cast<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>().Where(item => item.Name == "Resources").Single();

    // Delete all existing .resx files within the project
    foreach (var item in resourcesFolder.ProjectItems.Cast<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>())
    {
        item.Delete();
    }

    // Iterate over all files on the disk
    foreach (var resourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(resourcesPath, "*.resx"))
    {
        // Add them to the project ...
        var createdItem = resourcesFolder.Collection.AddFromFile(resourceFile);
        // and mess a little bit around in the properties.
        createdItem.Properties.Item("CustomTool").Value = "ResXFileCodeGenerator";
    }
#>
```

Answer (score 1):

Linked files in combination with partial classes looks like the solution for your problem. Make your data builder software emit code like this:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
   public void SomeFunction1()
   {
   }
}
```

and in your project create class like this:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public void MyOtherFunction()
    {
    }
}
```

include generated file in solution (Add->Existing Item->Add As Link) and compiler will merge contents of those 2 files into single class definition.

See more on partial classes in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx. Compiler can even automatically remove not implemented method definitions along with the calls. AFAIK this feature was designed specifically for working with generated sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can have linked files.

One project has the original file, and the second one have only a link to that file.
Look here for details: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)